# How do I speed up Java Google App Engine deployment?

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, deployment, oauth

I'm developing a test app with GWT+Java-AppEngine and the deploys are so heavy and slow.

I read about minimize permutations or parallel compilation of GWT, but my internet connection is not so good and I think that I'm uploading heavy files to App Engine Server.

How can I optimize this? Can I check where is the bottleneck?

The reason that I need several deployments is because I'm using Google API's through OAuth and I can't set localhost as a callback (I do?).

Comment: You should test your applications in the development server.

Comment: yep, but I'm using Google API's and I can't register localhost as a domain in Google Domains to set it as a callback after OAuth Authentication

Comment: maybe you could get your local machine a dyndns hostname and make it accessible from the internet ?

Comment: I don't understand how a dyndns could help here ^^? Could you explain a bit more? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure about your scenario, so I will try to guess your intentions.

For development purposes, you really should be working on the local server, it comes with all the API's and stubs for things like user login and what not. That is instantaneous. Once you are happy with your local app and it is time to upload, then if AppEngine overlord decides to take time due to AppSize/Slow Connection/Service outage/random act of diety, there is little one can do.

Considering that one doesn't deploy every hour, I think your time would be better spent on the app, instead of tuning the upload time.

I am assuming you are already following http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/uploading.html

I personally have dabbled with appengine but the python version, and it may take a few mins but once upload is complete, you are good to go.

> > maybe you could get your local machine a dyndns hostname and make it accessible from the internet ? –

I think what Bastian meant was as follows (assuming Dev server can actually serve domains - i am not sure about that)

1. Have your domain host (example.com) maintain an 'A' record pointing to your development machine IP address [hence when you do example.com, your dev machine responds as the server]
2. This means if you setup DNS records to point to ghs.google.com or whatever, you will have to change them (DNS records take a while to propagate depending on host)
3. Once you are happy, and you want to test on google, you still have to 'upload' before you can try it on appspot.com and ofcourse change DNS entries again so example.com works off google servers.

Too much work in my opinion. Better to use dev server in local machine.

Have a break while you are uploading. Have a KitKat to kill time :)

Comment: Thanks Nasir, currently my problem is focused on test the application with Google OAuth Authentication. I need to serve ot Google a callback URL where I get the authentication tokens. I have to achieve that my development machine serves a public dyndns address to get the OAuth to work, I think that's my only option

Comment: Finally I config an DynDNS to get callbacks in my local machine and no "test uploads" are needed.  Thank you